# Stopping HTTP Request Timeout in Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, jasper-reports

I have an application and I am generating Jasper Reports from it. But when I make request to generate the report, the time taken for the application to generate the report is quite long because the data set is very large(~100K rows) for the report.

So, by the time the report is generated successfully, the HTTP request gets timed out and the report is never downloaded.

How can I prevent this from happening?

The application is build with Spring 3.0, Hibernate and JasperReports.

Comment: From where are you getting the time out, Server or Browser?

Comment: Along with time out there must be some other exception generated from your application. Please share that exception and problem code so that everone can understand your problem well and answer.

Comment: Its the browser timeout. There is no exception because the report gets generated eventually, but not pushed to browser as the request has timed out already.

Comment: How long before it times out? 2 minutes? 30 minutes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that your session is expiring at 20 minutes, try editing `tomcat6/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<session-config>
    <!-- Default to 20 minute session timeouts -->
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Also make use of 'Run in background' (right-click) which will save the output for you like a schedule.

You can check `tomcat6/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log` for any error messages.

Comment: boooo, who is hating on my answer without leaving a comment. To clarify,  this answer is only for the browser timeout when using the jasper reports UI

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution will be to add a timeout parameter to your Http request.

A cleaner solution is:

- Kick off the report generation with one Ajax request (Use spring scheduler to schedule for immediate execution)
- Poll from the browser to check the status of the report; when found done, present the report.